# Rails 3.2.x: How to use variables in call to link_to from my view template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a object menu item made available by controller to the corresponding view template. This object has two fields: label and link.

I initiated this object like following in the controller:

```
// first param is for label and second for link.
menuitem = MenuItem.new("Hello","Say_hello_path")
```

In the view template I am typing this:

```
<%= link_to menuitem.label, menuitem.link %>
```

I expect this to result in: `<a href="/say/hello">Hello</a>`

but I am getting: `<a href="Say_hello_path">Hello</a>`

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second item in MenuItem.new("Hello","Say_hello_path")  is a string.  When you call <%= link_to menuitem.label, menuitem.link %>, it is just putting the string.

You can try the following

```
// first param is for label and second for link.
@menuitem = MenuItem.new("Hello", say_hello_path)
```

Or, you can try to eval the string in the link_to (you'll need to fix the case on the method name).

```
<%= link_to @menuitem.label, eval(@menuitem.link) %>
```

Eval isn't usually recommended, but may be what you need in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Only instance variables are added to the view bag. So in both files you need to change menuitem to @menuitem.

Other than that, say_hello_path is a function, not a string, so you should remove the quotes, and probably make it all lowercase.